# In Eclipse Oxygen 3 Release this program dosn't call loop in its last interation while other IDE does it

Tags: java, eclipse

Why this code doesn't works on Eclipse but works fine on some other IDEs. The problem I am facing with the code is that Eclipse doesn't call the last loop while I tried running the same snippet on some online Java compilers it runs okay and call all the loops.

I'm using:

**Eclipse version: Oxygen 3 

Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_151" 

System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.**

Input Data:

`4
5 3
0 0 0 0 0
6 5
0 0 0 1 1 1
6 3
0 0 1 1 1 0
3 1
0 1 0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int loops = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        int noOfElements = sc.nextInt();
        int leapValue = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("loop get called" + i);

        int array[] = new int[noOfElements];

        for (int j = 0; j < noOfElements; j++) {
            int u = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(u);
            array[j] = u;
            System.out.println("Imcalled");    
        }
    }
}
```

**Ouput**

`loop get called0
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
loop get called1
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
loop get called2
0
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
1
Imcalled
0
Imcalled
loop get called3`

Comment: How do you know the last loop isn't called? How do you notice the error? Only by the display?

Comment: Hey Alex, After the loop get called3 it should show the array elements. Like previous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with your code or not even with eclipse. Eclipse's Consul is not design for reading any input value rather it has been design for `standard output` and `standard error` messages. Even though it can read from the consul but that is not efficiently design . Better run you program from command line. First make jar file (right click on your project->export->jar) and call like `java -jar /path/to/your.jar`

Comment: Thank you Abhijit but it is tedious method as each time I make even small changes I have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I executed your code in 
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600 
Java & OS same as yours

It works well, not really sure why it isn't at your side. Try to install the version that I mentioned above and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Duho but due to some technical reasons I can't change my versions.

Comment: @Prashant, Yes if you have user input required.